# Is it possible to log how much gas was used during hardhat/ethers transaction?

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat

I am trying to estimate average gas cost per 10000 transactions i.e.

```
  const callMany = async () => {
    for (let i = 0; i <= 10000; i++) {
      const tx = await contract.doThing(1, `Val1`, {
        gasLimit: 100000
      });
      await tx.wait();
    }
  };

  await callMany();
```

But I can't seem to find if its possible / how to log gas used by each transaction in the loop.

Answer (score 10):

For we worked:

```
const receipt = await tx.wait();
const gasUsed = BigInt(receipt.cumulativeGasUsed) * BigInt(receipt.effectiveGasPrice);
```

Answer (score 6):

You seem to be using ethers.js, while I am not actively using it the [documentation](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/single-page/#/v5/api/contract/contract/-%23-contract-functionsSend) states :

> If the wait() method on the returned TransactionResponse is called,
> there will be additional properties on the receipt

The documentation of the full receipt object can be found [here](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/single-page/#/v5/api/providers/types/-%23-providers-TransactionReceipt).

So you should use something like :

```
const receipt = tx.wait();
const gasUsed = receipt.getTransactionReceipt().gasUsed;
```

I don't understand however why you would need such functionality, smart contracts are deterministic and OP_CODES gas weights are fixed, unless some side effect forbids you to proceed with the computation inside the smart contract, I'd expect all of the iteration to consume the same amount of gas.

Comment: re. "I don't understand however why you would need such functionality": you sometimes need to separate out how much gas was used by a transaction from how much ether was received or sent in the transaction.

Answer (score 3):

[myBigNumber.mul()](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/bignumber/#BigNumber--BigNumber--methods--math-operations) method of the BigNumber is the way to do multiplication ideally:

```js
const trans = await myContract.withdraw(myAddress, amount)
const receipt = await trans.wait()
const gasCostForTxn = receipt.gasUsed.mul(receipt.effectiveGasPrice)
console.log('gasCostForTxn:', gasCostForTxn)
```

Answer (score 2):

I use this code

```js
    const txReceipt = await provider.getTransactionReceipt(txArbitrage.hash);
             console.log(txArbitrage.hash);
             const effGasPrice = txReceipt.effectiveGasPrice;
             const txGasUsed = txReceipt.gasUsed;
             const gasUsedETH = effGasPrice * txGasUsed;
             console.log(
               "Total Gas USD: " +
                 ethers.utils.formatEther(gasUsedETH.toString()) * 1580 // exchange rate today
             );
             expect(gasUsedETH).not.equal(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

@kornelHub answer works except you might need to pay attention to the property of gas used.

There are two properties explain the used gas amount, one is `gasUsed`, and another is `cumulativeGasUsed`, as the [documentation](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/types/#providers-TransactionReceipt) says, `cumulativeGasUsed` is sum of gas used by all the transactions from the first one up to the current one inside the same block, while `gasUsed` represents only for the current transaction.